# Evaluation of a contour integral

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

I'm working on the integral $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\cos(x)}{x^{\alpha}}dx$  where $\alpha \in (0,1)$. After I convert it to a complex integral (with integrand $f(z) = \frac{e^{iz}}{z^{\alpha}}$ and the contour given in the picture), I was able to work out all pieces but one: the integral over $C_{R}$. The solution claims that this integral vanishes when $R \to \infty$. However, after one parametrizes this quantity, one obtains
\begin{align*}
\lvert \int_{C_R} f(z)dz \rvert &= \lvert \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{e^{iRe^{it}}}{(Re^{it})^{\alpha}}iRe^{it} dt \rvert \\
& \leqslant \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{e^{-R\sin(t)}}{R^{\alpha}}R dt \\
& \leqslant \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} R^{1-\alpha} dt
\end{align*}
which is not the desired result. Is there any way to see why this integral vanishes?
[image]

Comment: Use $\sin t \ge \frac{2 t}{\pi}$ for $t \in [0,\pi/2]$ (Jensen's inequality) ..

Comment: I see. But I still don't see how one can get rid of $t$ in the integrand? @r9m

Comment: @Yoona you don't need to do so, integrate $e^{-\frac{R2t}{\pi}}$

Comment: @r9m This is Jordan inequality. Not Jensen inequality

Comment: @MohammadW.Alomari ok good to know. How does one prove Jordan inequality?

Comment: @r9m Welcome, you can check this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan%27s_inequality
where proof without words is presented. About Jordan Lemma, you can also check https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan%27s_lemma

If you need more information, please you can contact me.